# Are there any side effects for C code using data structure allocated using operator new

Tags: c++, c

## a.h

```
struct S1{...};

extern "C" struct S1 *f();

extern "C" void freeS1(struct S1 *ptr);
```

## a.cpp

```
extern "C" struct S1 *f() {
    struct S1 *ptr = new struct S1();
    ...
    return ptr;
};

extern "C" void freeS1(struct S1 *ptr) { 
    delete ptr;
};
```

## b.c

```
struct S1 *ptr = f();
.....
freeS1(ptr);
```

Comment: I still don't understand what you're actually asking.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: You have been a member for well over two years, and apparenty still haven't read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Or [taken the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) or [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Code only questions are generally not useful.

Comment: From the title, I believe the OP is asking if there are any problems using `new`/`delete`-managed memory from C. To which of course the answer is "no" (providing you don't mix `new`/`free()` or `malloc()`/`delete`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Memory is memory, it doesn't really matter which allocator provided it, as long as it's correctly aligned and allocation and deallocation functions are correctly matched (and the structure definition is the same). There should be no problem.

Comment: What happen when new throw a exeption?

Comment: Implementation dependent, the standard isn't concerned about foreign stack frames. But in general, you don't want to have exceptions traverse C code, even if the platform itself handles unwinding nicely (e.g. VC++ on Windows, where C++ exceptions are bolt on SEH) typically C code doesn't expect it. So, I would say that calling the `nothrow` `new` overload would be a better idea.